# Do Not Load iFrame Google Map Until Lightbox Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, iframe, fancybox-2

I am embedding a few maps onto a page using the Google Maps iFrame Embed. These maps are loaded into a page and displayed in a lightbox (with other information) upon click. Is it possible to not load the iFrame content *until* the lightbox link is actually clicked?

I do not want to load 10+ maps when only one or two might be needed.

Is this possible to do?

I am using Fancybox 2 as the lightbox and jQuery 2.1.

I have considered using jQuery to inject the iFrame code on click but I am unsure of the best method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be different ways, 1 possible:

store the `src` in another attribute of the `iframe`(e.g. `data-src`) and assign the `src` when the lightbox opens:

```
$(".selector").fancybox({
    afterLoad:function(){
        this.content.find('iframe')
       .each(function(i,f){ 
          f=$(f);
          if(!f.attr('src')) {
             f.attr('src',f.data('src'));
          } 
        });               
    }
});
```

Comment: That worked well. Thank You. I did see this error in Firebug:  

`...e(d)}catch(k){e(1,k);return}b(a)}else e(0,null)};c[gb]("GET",a,!0);c.send(null)}...

init_embed.js (line 28)` - I am unsure if it is on my page or if it is Google Maps? It doesn't seem to cause any problem on the page itself.

Comment: the error is forced by google(I guess an attempt to access the parent document)